# Can't connect to external MySQL server. IP changes to a local ip

Tags: mysql

I've encountered an odd problem and I'm unsure what is causing it as it has been completely fine prior to today.

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL Server but it is changing the IP address to another address that represents my local IP.

**Example**

*(I've replaced the IPs and domains for obvious reasons)*

I'm trying to connect to:

```
43.124.65.13:3306
```

But connection is replacing it to:

```
 host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net
```

as shown on the error that is returned back to me.

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net'`

The IP **12.382.224.82** is my own network IP from whatsmyip.org and googling as12265.net leads to multiple logs referring to Talk-Talk which is my ISP.

Any idea what could be causing this? I've tried disabling the firewall, windows defender, and malwarebytes premium but it is still happening. I can connect to the MySQL server fine on other devices too so it's just this one.

I have just tried connecting via proxy and now it is changing the IP to the same one as the proxy I'm connected to. Perhaps this is a MySQL setting?

Windows 10

MySQL 5.7.26

Comment: "connection is replacing it to"...how are you observing this exactly? It's unclear what software (or hardware) you think is modifying the target IP address, or why. This shouldn't happen. You might get a firewall blocking the request, but I can't think of any reason it would try and modify the target IP or hostname. You haven't got a dodgy entry in your `hosts` file or something, perhaps?? Also please show us precisely how you're connecting, and what message you get when you try.

Comment: Anyway this isn't really a programming question, it's more of a networking issue by the sounds of it (unless you are using some of your own program code to try and make the connection? It's not really clear.). You might get better answers on serverfault perhaps, or maybe the DBA stackexchange.

Comment: I've tried connecting to the server via my web application using WAMP as well as using a MySQL adminstration tool (HeidiSQL). Both give the exact same problem. I've already tried checking the hosts file but there is nothing there that suggests it is the cause of it.

Comment: @Echoing ADyson - It's not at all clear what messages or log entries you are seeing that leads you to believe the "connection is replacing it".  There is a MySQL server setting `skip-name-resolve` that disables reverse DNS lookup. But that would only affect user authentication on the MySQL server. If someone changed the `skip-name-resolve` setting, or changed DNS entries, then we'd expect to see errors from MySQL like `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'host'`,  but not an IP address replaced in the connection. (The question fails to adequately describe the observed behavior)

Comment: I am connecting to the MySQL server using the following IP: `43.124.65.13:3306` but I am getting the following error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net'. The credentials are correct but the host name is not. It is trying to connect to an invalid host.

Comment: `host-12-382-224-82.as12265.net` is not the address of the MySQL server. That's the `Host` value of the MySQL client attempting to connect. MySQL Server is doing a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address of the client (that MySQL Server sees the connection request received from.)  Use MySQL Server `skip-name-resolve` option to disable reverse DNS lookup).  MySQL Server is checks for a matching user@host  (matching on both *user* and *host*). The most likely explanation for the observed behavior is that it's not finding a match. (We would get the same error if the password didn't match, et al.)

Comment: Note that a MySQL user is identified by two parts: `Host` and `User` we can see this in a query of mysql.user table) Note that 'user'@'127.0.0.1' and 'user'@'%' are two *different* MySQL users, with separate authentication, separate privileges.  What that MySQL error message is saying is that MySQL server is *not* finding a matching row in mysql.user table.

Comment: `skip-name-resolve` seems to have solved it. Thank you very much! I've been trying to fix this damn thing all day!